# Issue when compiling libstdc++ with clang

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++, libstdc++

I'm noticing an issue when using clang to compile libstdc++ (i.e., GNU's implementation of C++'s Standard Library). **The question is, provided the issue is confirmed, whom should I report it to?**

It happens when move assigning a `std::vector<X, A<X>>` and the conditions are:

1. `X`'s move-constructor might throw (though I'm *assigning* and not constructing);
2. `A<X>` does not propagate on move-assignment and allocators used by source and target vectors do not compare equal.

A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) follows (see it [live](https://godbolt.org/z/MtIOKE)). Unfortunately it contains a bit of boiler plate and the most important parts are indicated by comments.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

struct X {
    X() = default;
    X(const X&) = default;

    // Move constructor might throw
    X(X&&) noexcept(false) = default;

    // Track calls to assignment functions
    X& operator=(const X&) {
        putchar('c'); return *this;
    }
    X& operator=(X&&) noexcept(true) {
        putchar('m'); return *this;
    }
};

unsigned counter = 0;

template <typename T>
struct A : std::allocator<T> {

    template <typename U>
    struct rebind { using other = A<U>; };

    A() : std::allocator<T>(), id(++counter) {}

    // Does not propagate
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::false_type;

    // Does not always compare equal
    using is_always_equal = std::false_type;
    bool operator ==(const A& o) { return id == o.id; }
    bool operator !=(const A& o) { return id != o.id; }

    unsigned id;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<X, A<X>> a(2), rv(2);
    a = std::move(rv);
}
```

As far as I know, clang++ uses libstdc++ by default and using libc++ is an opt-in through `-stdlib=libc++`. Running the code above (again, built with clang and libstdc++) displays `cc` which means the two elements of `rv` are *copy-assigned* into `a`.

However, quoting [[container.requirements.general]/4, Table 83](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/container.requirements#tab:containers.container.requirements)

> > "All existing elements of a are either move assigned to or destroyed"

(This is further confirmed by 
[[container.requirements.general]/16, Table 86](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/container.requirements#tab:containers.allocatoraware).)

On the other hand by switching either compiler to gcc or library to libc++, we get `mm` which is aligned with the quote above. This also happens by changing the exception specification of `X(X&&)` to `noexcept(true)` whereas that of `operator =(X&&)` seems irrelevant.

Am I missing something? If not, whom should I report the issue to? It's either libstdc++ or clang. (I think this might not be obvious.) I tend to think it's the latter since, AFAIK, clang is supposed to support libstdc++ and not the other way around.

(**Side note**: the code above can reveal at least another issue, namely, removing `rebind` from `A` makes clang/libstdc++ fail to compile whereas clang/libc++ succeeds. It looks to me that in this case the blame is reversed and falls on libstdc++ but that's not part of my question.)

Comment: As to your side note: if you remove `rebind`, then your allocator is not an allocator, so there's no question of blame.

Comment: And even with `rebind` your allocator is still not an allocator; copies of the same allocator must compare equal.

Comment: @TC In C++17 [allocator.requirements/2, Table 3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/allocator.requirements#2) `rebind` is optional.

Comment: @T.C. Re equality, I was trying to keep the post as simple as possible, you're right. So I've updated the post to implement equality properly. There's no difference on the behaviour.

Comment: `rebind` is generally optional, but in this case without it you'd get `std::allocator`'s `rebind` instead, which means that your allocator has a bogus rebind.

Comment: @T.C.Oh, yes. Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libstdc++ is using `move_if_noexcept` [for this](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/463c873e992b9a84638f4d2cd49089d83a0a186d/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L1831-L1832), which it probably shouldn't. Bug reports should go to them.

The rest appears to be due to divergence over how to handle a defaulted member function with an exception specification mismatch. This was ill-formed, then deleted, then valid. See [P1286R2](https://wg21.link/p1286r2) for the history.

- Clang thinks "ill-formed" then "valid", so for the versions in which it compiles, `move_if_noexcept` will attempt to copy.
- GCC thinks "ill-formed" then "deleted". But a deleted move constructor that is defined to as defaulted is ignored by overload resolution, so move construction falls back to using the defaulted *copy* constructor, which is implicitly noexcept. As a result, `move_if_noexcept` will think that the type is nothrow move constructible and attempt to move.

Comment: Regarding `move_if_no_except` I agree this is relevant and it looks wrong to use it. However, I'm not sure this is a complete answer. As I said in the OP, when the code is compiled with g++ then we get two moves as expected. In addition, I've just realised that two flavours of clang experimental (P1144 and concepts) in godbolt also yield the two moves I was  expecting. These new discoveries makes me even more inclined to think clang is wrong.

Comment: Those two experimental clang configs bring in libc++, as you can tell from the `__1` in the vector.

Comment: Everything is clear now, thanks. In addition, when I replace `= default;` with `{}` in `X`'s move constructor g++ changes behaviour and instead of moves make copies (matching clang's behaviour).

Comment: Bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92124